# git fixing old merge and keeping subsequent commits

Tags: git

initial situation:

```
M0 ----- M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4 -- M5
|-- A1 --/\    |                 |
\-- B1 ---|----/                 |
           --------- A2 ---------/
```

2 developers are working on one repository, both start by branching from M0. Dev A is working on branch A1, merging it when finished as M1 into main. He directly creates a new branch, working on feature A2. B is working in the meantime on B1, and merges when finished into M2. However, during this merge some important changes made in M1 are discarded. B creates more commits on top (M3, M4). When A is finished working on A2 and wants to merge back into master (M5), changes which were already introduced in M1 and were therefore part of M2 are deleted/ do not even show up as conflict.
(-> I guess this is the expected behaviour as M4 and A2 share the same parent M1?)

current state:

```
M0 ----- M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4
|-- A1 --/\    /
\-- B1 ---|---<
          |----\----- A2 ----------\
          M1---M2*-- M3* -- M4* -- M5
```

For fixing this, I created a new branch from M1 and redid the merge (M2*). Then I did a rebase to add M3* and M4* on top of M2*. In the end I was able to merge A2 into M4*, getting the desired M5. Unfortunately, M4 was already pushed to origin. So if I want to open a pull-request on M5, this will again introduce the wrong version of M2.
-> Therefore, my next move would be to do a `git push --force origin master` (while making sure dev B already pushed all his changes). Is this whole workaround recommended or is there a better way of dealing with described situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "rewriting history" is an option, I would checkout `M2`, correct it and amend it (let's call it `M2'` when amended), then I would cherry-pick `M2..M4` and then would merge `A2` creating `M5'`. Then I would point the branch (main?) to `M5'` and that would be the end of it (force-push to wherever it's required).

As a side note, **no**, there should be no conflict when merging `A2` with `M4` because the code was removed and that's it doesn't matter the ancestry (unless the code removed involves code that is touched by the work done on `A2`).

Comment: _"If "rewriting history" is an option, I would..."_

Alright, so this version is quite similar to the one I suggested (by correcting M2, however I guess I have to manually check what's missing compared to redoing the merge? The suggested cherry-picking of M2..M4 should be then equivalent to rebasing).

_"there should be no conflict when merging A2 with M4"_

Do you mean the old M4, as described in the initial graph? If I try this merge no conflict arises, but the parts which were not included in M2 are just dropped, which is what I don't want.

Comment: Well, if you wan to try redoing the merge for M2, that's fine... whatever you feel is the right way to get the dropped parts back into the busted M2. Then the question about M4: yes, the _old_ original M4... and the _old_ original M2 when doing `git cherry-pick M2..M4`.

Comment: okay, the first part is clear now. 
My question concerning your statement _"there should be no conflict when merging A2 with M4"_ referred to the merging instead of the cherry-picking you mentioned. So if I try this merge with the old A2 and M4, no conflict arises, but the parts which were not included in M2 are just dropped, which is what I don't want.

Comment: what part of "we will create a (fixed) M2 revision that includes those parts that were dropped from it" is not clear yet? once you have those parts on M2', cherry-picking M2..M4 will still hold them.... and merging with A2, those sections would still be there.

Comment: Alright, now I understand. You referred in "_there should be no conflict when merging A2 with M4_" to M4 on top of the fixed M2 and not the old unfixed M2. Thanks!

Comment: No no.... that's _another_ question not related to any of the work that I described. You were saying `I was expecting to see a conflict when I merged M2 (original M2) with A2 (Original A2) because of the shared M1 ancestor and the deleted code` . To that question I'm answering: A conflict is _not_ to be expected, unless the two branches differ on a section of code related to the deleted code. Say, on M4 it's deleted (deleted on M2, remember?) and on A2 it's modified (some piece of the deleted sections on M2). _Then_ you would get a conflict (and other situations like that).